# Arrow pathways in QGIS using geometry generator

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, virtual-layer, geometry-generator, flow-map

I’ve been trying to draw trade pathway arrows following the fabulous posts from @underdark for Flow Maps on QGIS from 2019-05-04 (https://anitagraser.com/2019/05/04/flow-maps-in-qgis-no-plugins-needed/).

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to make the software draw the lines to connect the nodes with the edges. I have tried several ways but nothing is working. My goal is to connect the trade happening between one U.S. state (i.e., Wyoming) and other U.S. states with the width of the line representing how big the trade is on each pathway.

Using other post (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnNnBQI__HA), I was able to connect the one state with the rest of the states using the geometry generator tool but it only draws lines of the same width.

My dataset looks like this (in total, I have 26 rows):

| T_State | T_Lon | T_Lat | D_State | D_Lon | D_Lat | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WY | -107.55144 | 42.99963 | AL | -86.82676 | 32.79354 | 9496187 |
| WY | -107.55144 | 42.99963 | AR | -92.4392 | 34.89977 | 9738706 |
| WY | -107.55144 | 42.99963 | AZ | -111.66457 | 34.29323 | 3595843 |